# Alembic eye mesh not following the character body

Tags: mesh, alembic

I'm trying to export Malcolm(Animschool rig) from maya to blender as an alembic file. But after exporting his eye mesh break the connection with the body and they come on grid in blender. Any valuable suggestions would be helpful. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the answer after spending my entire day to get that eye mesh. Solution was: My rig eyeball has the same naming convention and alembic dont read same name file so i had to separately export the eye mesh from maya to blender. And now its working:)[image]